# Object ID and Installation ID in parse SDK giving null value

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to get `installation id` and `object id` from parse by using below code:

```
Parse.initialize(this, Constants.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, Constants.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId() and 
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId().
```

I am using above code in application class of android. both giving me null. and sometimes they give values to me, but not showing its entry in parse console. can anyone please help me this, what exactly wrong i am doing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you subscribe for parse push then it update records in Installation table.

> ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("APP_NAME");

After subscribing call on Installation to get objectId and installationId.

Your Code like  this :

In Your Application class

```
 Parse.initialize(this, Constants.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, Constants.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
 ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("APP_NAME");
```

In your Activity where you want to get this id's :
`ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId() and     ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId()`.